# why mysql server character cannot be set as the setting(utf8) in my-default.ini(windows)?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, my.cnf

### Here is my-default.ini

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-configuration-defaults.html
# *** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. It's a template which will be copied to the
# *** default location during install, and will be replaced if you
# *** upgrade to a newer version of MySQL.

[mysqld]

# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M

# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin

# These are commonly set, remove the # and set as required
default-character-set = utf8
character_set_server = utf8
basedir = D:\Program Files\mysql
datadir = D:\Program Files\mysql\data

# port = .....
# server_id = .....


# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M 

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES 

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql.server]
default-character-set = utf8

[mysqld_safe]
default-character-set = utf8

[client]
default-character-set = utf8
```

## But in command line

```
mysql> show variables like 'character%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                  |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                   |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                   |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                   |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                 |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                   |
| character_set_server     | latin1                                 |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                   |
| character_sets_dir       | D:\Program Files\mysql\share\charsets\ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------+
8 rows in set

mysql>
```

- as you see,I really do lots of settings in the my-defualt.ini,but every time MYSQL server start , character_set_server is always latin1.
- I want it to be utf8,how can I make it?
- I want to why?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to copy `my-default.ini` to `my.ini`, since the latter is what `mysqld` looks for by default.

Otherwise, I can't duplicate your problem.

I'm running 5.6.12 on Windows 8.1.  Here is the test case, starting with no mention of `character_set_server` in **my.ini**:

```
mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                         |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                          |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                          |
| character_set_database   | latin1                                        |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                        |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                          |
| character_set_server     | latin1                                        | -- Note
| character_set_system     | utf8                                          |
| character_sets_dir       | c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\share\charsets\ |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create database whatischarset;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> show create database whatischarset;
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Database      | Create Database                                                          |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| whatischarset | CREATE DATABASE `whatischarset` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */ |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

At this point, I added `character_set_server = utf8` to the `[mysqld]` section of the appropriate `my.ini`; then restarted mysqld.  Now...

```
mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                         |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                          |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                          |
| character_set_database   | latin1                                        |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                        |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                          |
| character_set_server     | utf8                                          | -- Note
| character_set_system     | utf8                                          |
| character_sets_dir       | c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\share\charsets\ |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create database whatischarset2;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create database whatischarset2;
+----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Database       | Create Database                                                         |
+----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| whatischarset2 | CREATE DATABASE `whatischarset2` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */ |
+----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How does this compare to what you did?

Comment: P.S. Thanks for forcing me to figure out what `character_set_server` is all about.  It seems to _only_ provide a _default_ for `CREATE DATABASE`.  Hardly worth worrying about.